# How to configure dnat to a ssh forwarded port

Tags: iptables, nat

I've got two machines and I can only ssh from one to the other (why? ask me again sometime...).  So I'd like to hack this so I can effectively ssh both ways.

What I've done one a device called *h-linux-a* (whose IP address is 10.10.20.20)

```
ssh -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 h-linux-b
```

on h-linux-b, I've tested that I can successfully connect back to h-linux-a by doing

```
ssh -p 2222 127.0.0.1
```

so on the h-linux-b I've added:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.10.20.20 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2222
```

and when I do

```
ssh 10.10.20.20
```

my ssh just hangs there.  I see the hit counter going up (by one, so no retries) on iptables, and I've checked tcpdump on the ephemeral port on h-linux-a to see if I was getting traffic coming back (I don't see anything except keepalives).

So it seems like my iptables command is the problem. I don't use the INPUT chain much, mostly PREROUTING and POSTROUTING, so I don't know the nuances.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.10.20.20 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2222
```

Try:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.10.20.20 --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 2222
```

The redirect chain allows you to loop back traffic to the same machine.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get back to work, but do I have to add 10.10.20.20 on the loopback interface for this to work?

Comment: What? No, that's not quite how things work.